# Convert a Column's type using its position/index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, type-conversion

I am reading some `.csv` files from a folder. I am trying to create a list of data frames from using each file.

In some files the column values, i.e. `Quantity` is in `str` and `float64` data types. Therefore, I am trying to convert the that column `quantity` into `int`.

I am accessing my columns using its position/index (For automation purposes).

Out of all data frames from a list, this is one of them,

```
    CustName    ProductID   Quantity
0   56MED       110         '1215.0'
1   56MED       112         5003.0
2   56MED       114         '6822.0'
3   WillSup     2285        5645.0
4   WillSup     5622        6523.0
5   HammSup     9522        1254.0
6   HammSup     6954        5642.0
```

Therefore, I have my looks like this,

```
df.columns[2] = pd.to_numeric(df.columns[2], errors='coerce').astype(str).astype(np.int64)
```

I am getting,

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations

Prior to this, I tried,

```
df.columns[2] = pd.to_numeric(df.columns[2], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(str).astype(np.int64)
```

However, I got this error,

> AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'

There are posts that have using column names directly, but not columns position. How can I convert my column into `int` using the column position/index in `pnadas`?

My `pandas` version

```
print(pd.__version__)
>> 0.23.3
```

Comment: Try, `df[df.columns[3]]`

Comment: df.columns[3] is a point to a column header, this is not want you wan to do.  You can use `df.iloc[:,3]`.

Comment: @ScottBoston I am still getting `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'fillna'` for your suggestion :(

Comment: Can you add some data and the full code to generate this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.columns[2]` returns a **scalar**, in this case a string.

To access a series use either `df['Quantity']` or `df.iloc[:, 2]`, or even `df[df.columns[2]]`. Instead of the repeated transformations, if you are sure you have data which should be integers, use `downcast='integer'`.

All these are equivalent:

```
df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')

df.iloc[:, 2] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 2], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')

df[df.columns[2]] = pd.to_numeric(df[df.columns[2]], errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```

Comment: thank you, but not sure if you tried my `df` in the post, I get `NaN` value for strings i.e `'1215.0'`. Also, data frame's dtype changes from `object` to `float64` not `int`. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to remove those quotes from your strings first, then use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df.iloc[:, 2] = pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:, 2].str.strip('\'')).astype(int)
```

OR from @jpp:

```
df['Quantity'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity'].str.strip('\''), errors='coerce', downcast='integer')
```

Output, df.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 7 entries, 0 to 6
Data columns (total 3 columns):
CustName     7 non-null object
ProductID    7 non-null int64
Quantity     7 non-null int32
dtypes: int32(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 196.0+ bytes
```

Output:

```
  CustName  ProductID  Quantity
0    56MED        110      1215
1    56MED        112      5003
2    56MED        114      6822
3  WillSup       2285      5645
4  WillSup       5622      6523
5  HammSup       9522      1254
6  HammSup       6954      5642
```